# My activity don't show map but a black background

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to write my first android application. I've this problem

When i try to show this activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_map);
```

This is the file xml of the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

The application show a black background empty and black and the log file is this:

```
02-20 21:33:45.113: D/libEGL(19145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-20 21:33:45.113: D/libEGL(19145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-20 21:33:45.123: D/libEGL(19145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-20 21:33:45.153: D/OpenGLRenderer(19145): Enabling debug mode 0
02-20 21:33:45.223: E/SensorManager(19145): thread start
02-20 21:33:45.233: D/SensorManager(19145): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= MPU-     6050 Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener=    android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@419da6c0
02-20 21:33:59.237: W/dalvikvm(19145): VFY: unable to resolve static field 849  (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
02-20 21:33:59.237: D/dalvikvm(19145): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
```

This activity only have to show the map, why don't works?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: have add the google-map api key

Comment: I've  just obtained my api keys and added it in file manifest. Is this that you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> `unable to resolve static field`

That sort of error probably means that you are trying to run mismatched versions of your code together. Clean your build and rebuild everything, and try again.